# Can't see variables from one method in another

Tags: c#, scope

I'm trying to read something defined before but code can't see it

```
void OnExplosiveThrown(BasePlayer player, BaseEntity entity, InputState input)
{
    if (Test == true )
    {
        var abc = entity as test;
    }
}

void Unload(BaseEntity entity)        ------//This CODE CANT SEE abc //------
{
     entity.Kill(abc);
}
```

It says abc does not exist in the current context.

How can I fix this?

Ty,

Comment: *Where* you declare a variable determines its scope (where it can be used/seen/referenced)

Comment: so I must define it before?

Comment: Move it outside the method.  So put before first line string abc = "";  Then remove var before abc on fifth line.

Comment: abc doesn't exist in the Unload method. Sounds like you need to read about scope; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awt60xs1.aspx

Comment: @TanvirArjel Obviously the type is `test`. There are plenty of cases where C# programmers do not agree on whether `var` should be used, but to the best of my knowledge, support for `var` where the type is explicitly specified in the initialiser is nearly universal.

Comment: Don't know why people are giving down vote to this question. May be this question is very simple but he can be very new to C# programming!

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `abc` inside the function, so it has been local scoped variable which cannot be accessed from outside this function. To access this variable from another function or from outside this function, you have to declare this variable in global scope as follows:

```
test abc = null;

void OnExplosiveThrown(BasePlayer player, BaseEntity entity, InputState input)
{
    if (Test == true )
     {
        abc = entity as test;
     }

}

void Unload(BaseEntity entity)        ------//This CODE CANT SEE abc //------
{
     entity.Kill(abc);
}
```

Comment: But I cannot define a var outside of void.

Comment: Yes! You cannot because according to C# documentation `var is an implicitly typed local variable declaration` and that why does not allow global variable declaration using `var`. To declare global variable, your variable type must be explicit with an initial value.